# Code 'ghosts' in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, draw

The problem I have run into twice now is that my program seems to be running code that no longer exists. I figure that some old version is stuck some how but have no idea how to get the compiler to run the updated code I've written.

The way I have spotted the problem is by observing that bit maps I've loaded keep getting drawn even after I've removed instructions to do so. The problem persists even after removing every reference to the image in question, content load lines included.

The first time this happened restarting the compiler didn't fix the problem but restarting the computer did. Now the problem has persisted after a full shutdown.

I m using ms C# 2008 express edition if that has any bearing.

Comment: I would use dotpeek or reflector to decompile your binaries to validate that the code being run is actually what you expect.

Comment: What kind of application is this?  WPF? WinForms? WebForms?

Comment: Sometimes the debugger can hold on to a stale pdb file. Close visual studio, delete obj/bin then open and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Clean build sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Try Build -> Configuration Manager and make sure all the projects in your solution are checked.

Comment: I don't know dotpeek or reflector but that sounds useful.  I m certain that the code being run is not what I expect.

Comment: @AndrewBell spots's suggestion is also something that can happen now and then. +1

Comment: Could this be a problem with the content unload?

Comment: Yes, this can happen especially when working in a team environment and a solution with many projects. Sometimes a developer will uncheck a project they're not working on to speed up their compile time. The unfortunate part is when they check in the .sln and all the devs don't catch that change.

Comment: I got it ... for now.  @spots  the configuration manager was selecting the debug project, the only one there.  I removed the .pdb file found in the bin subfolders and re-running the program got it working.  Now if only I knew why that happened in the first place

Answer (score 3):

My first thought would be that the build is failing and that Visual Studio is running the old version.  I don't have VS 2008, but in VS 2010 the option to change this option is in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out where the mismatch is coming from. 
What happens when you run the .exe from outside VS? What about from inside VS? Can you verify that after a build, the binary you're executing has an updated timestamp? Is the stale code in a .dll where the new version isn't getting pulled in?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happens when configuration profile is changed from debug. For instance if I am running the debug profile, it works. Then I change to the QA profile and make changes and then build the new assemblies. The assemblies are built to a directory called "QA" however, when I debug through visual studio it runs the code from the debug profile. I can remove references, recompile the code, visual studio will still run from the debug profile. It appears that none of the changes I made are in the code. When in reality I'm inadvertently running a old build.